# trigger a whatsapp message when new order

Tags: triggers, velo

Very newbie here and with Wix, it's the first time a client ask me for Wix and he has a special need.

Do you know if it's possible to send a whatsApp or Messenger to the owner of the shop when a new order is coming ?
I need this message contain the order item and the address to deliver.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an external API like [Twilio WhatsApp Business API](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp). You can trigger the message whenever a new order is created using the [Wix Store onNewOrder()](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-stores-backend/events/onneworder) event. Take a look at the [Twilio SMS API example](https://www.wix.com/velo/example/twilio-sms-integration) which should provide some insight.